# How to see only the local branches created by me on Magit?

Tags: magit

When I am working on the Command Line Interface, I can do:

```
$ git branch
```

Then, I can see all the local branches that *I have created*. On Magit, If I do `b l` (check out local branch), there is a prompt to answer. With the auto-complete, I can *find* all the local branches I created.

However, when I press `tab` to see the suggestions, **Magit lists absolutely all branches**, the ones I created locally and the ones pulled from the upstream remote repository.

Is there a way to limit the suggestions for the branch checkout only to the branches I have created?

Comment: I'm wondering why you'd want that in the first place, since non-local branches have a prefix. AFAIK, it's not possible. You can always run `M-! git branch RET`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick hack using `magit-read-local-branch`:

```lisp
(defun my-checkout-local-branch ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((branch (magit-read-local-branch "Branch: ")))
    (magit-checkout branch)))

(transient-append-suffix 'magit-branch "w"
  '("L" "my branch" my-checkout-local-branch))
```

Though it won't do stuff like filtering out the branch you're currently on.